# A problem of consecutive square full integers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, problem-solving, chinese-remainder-theorem

I am stuck with the following problem of number theory.A number $n$ is said to be square full if $p^2|n$ for some prime $p$.

Let $P(k)$  be the product of all primes $\leq k$.Then show that there exist $31\times 21$ integers $n$ with $1\leq n\leq P(31)^2$ such that $n+1,n+2,...,n+10$ are all square full and none of them are divisible by $31$.(Note that $31$ is the $11$ th prime in ascending order.)

I tried to do that with chinese remainder theorem on $n\equiv -1\pmod{2^2},n\equiv -2\pmod{3^2},...,n\equiv -10\pmod{{p_{10}}^2}$,but then I am stuck.Can someone give me some hint?

Comment: Seems like a good approach, what goes wrong?  Note that there's nothing special about the order you've put the $-1,-2, \cdots $ in.  Note too that if you start with $4\,|\,n+1$ then you get $4\,|\,n+5$ and $4\,|\,n+9$ for free.

Comment: Usually, a positive integer is called squareful if every prime factor occurs with multiplicity greater than $1$. For positive integers that are not squarefree , the usual terminology is simply "non-squarefree" or "not squarefree".

Comment: @Peter I have seen [a definition](https://oeis.org/wiki/Squareful_numbers) where *squarefull* means every prime factor has a multiplicity of 2 or more, while *squareful* (one l) means not square-free.  I doubt this subtlety will become popular but it at least suggest using either spelling may need to have a definition to avoid confusion